# Extra anchor tags in browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this weird issue with bootstrap site. I have a block for containing some products and I wrapped its content with anchor tag. To my surprise there are some anchor tags that I did not added. I know that browsers are trying to close tags by adding elements but I cannot find any issue with my HTML. I am using bootstrap version 3.

```css
.home-page-product-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.home-page-product-box > a {
  /*display: block;*/
}
.home-page-product-box > a > img {
  width: 100%;
}
.home-page-product-box > a > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: #03b6f0;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Lato-Medium;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 6px 14px;
}
.home-page-product-box > a > div:last-child {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #959595;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 home-page-product-box">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/a3/e1/04/a3e1048687b88956cd4edbc4b38a98b2.jpg" alt="">

          <div class="col-xs-12">
            Power Supplies
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer et adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
            <a href="#">View range</a>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But what I get is:

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 home-page-product-box">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/home-product-image1.jpg" alt="">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      Power Supplies
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer et adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
                                
    </a>
    <a href="#">View range</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Which links didn't you add?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do / what goes wrong. Please explain

Comment: Added anchor tag closed after 2nd child div and new anchor element wrapping 'Lorem ipsum' text, resulting the last anchor close tag to vanish.

Comment: You have nested anchors. This is incorrect. I don't help much more, because there are so many people that is really idiot downvoting in this stackoverflow web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue is here.

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/a3/e1/04/a3e1048687b88956cd4edbc4b38a98b2.jpg" alt="">

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    Power Supplies
  </div>

  <!--- HERE I THINK -->

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer et adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
    <a href="#">View range</a>
  </div>
</a>
```

You haven't closed the first link before you opened the second.

It appears that broswer has made fairly logical choice to close it for you where it thinks it appropriate because *links can't contain links*.

Answer (score -1):

You can't put block elements inside inline elements.

This is correct:

```
  <div><a></a></div>
```

This is incorrect:

```
  <a><div></div></a>
```

You must to rethink your structure if you want to write a clear, correct and cross-browser code.

You can replace block elements to inline and styling with css:

```
   <a><span></span></a>

   a > span { display:block }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Actually you can under HTML5